# Company ID not found issue occurs while connecting QuickBooks online ODBC driver

Tags: c#, odbc, quickbooks-online, dsn, qodbc

I have installed the trial version of the `QuickBooks Online ODBC (QODBC)` and configured the `DSN` named “**QuickBooks Online Data**” as well as "**QuickBooks Online Data QRemote**"

[image: QODBC driver configuration]

I have ensured both the connection using the test tool and I am able to query.

[image: QODBC]

[image: QRemote]

Now I am trying to connect the DSN named “**QuickBooks Online Data**” using the following C# code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string connectionString = "DSN=QuickBooks Online Data;";
  string sql = "select * from Account";

  OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
  DataTable t = new DataTable();
  using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
  {
   OdbcDataAdapter ds = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
   ds.Fill(t);
  }
}
```

While trying to connect to the QODBC using the console application, I am facing the below issue.

> Exception: ***ERROR [00000] [QODBC] QB Begin Session Failed. 657 - Company ID Not Found.
> Goto [QODBC Online Setup Screen] and Click [Connect to QuickBooks], Please Authorize QODBC Online to connect to Your QuickBooks Online Company.***

However, while trying to connect to the DSN named "**QuickBooks Online Data QRemote**" using the above C# code, I can able to connect and access the data source elements.

Can anyone please let me know what is the difference between the **QODBC connection** and **QRemote server connection** in QuickBooks online ODBC?

Also, anyone please guide me to find a proper solution to the mentioned issue?

Comment: Did you do this? "Goto [QODBC Online Setup Screen] and Click [Connect to QuickBooks], Please Authorize QODBC Online to connect to Your QuickBooks Online Company."

Comment: Yes. I tried out that and authorized QODBC. still issue not resolved.